# In C++, how do I use a private variable that is an array of objects?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, private-members

I'm trying to learn C++ and figuring out how to access a private member variable that is an array of objects. My objective is trying to print out the data that's in the array of objects. Suppose that my header looks like this.

```
using namespace std;

const unsigned MAX_RESULTS = 10;

class StudentRecords{
public:
  StudentRecords();

  //bunch of other getters and setters here

  Result GetResults() const; //my lame attempt at trying to access the obj-array private var

private:
  Result results[MAX_RESULTS]; // array of Result of MAX_RESULTS number of elements
  //+other private variables
};

ostream& operator <<( ostream& os, const StudentRecords& R);
```

In the above, there is supposed to be a private array of Result objects called results, which has a size of MAX_RESULTS, which is supposed to be 10 here. Now, using my overloaded operator << the idea is to print the contents of Result to 'file' so as to speak. Since it's an array, I want to print out all the results in the array using a for loop.

```
Result StudentRecords::GetResults() const
{
    return results[MAX_RESULTS];
}

ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, const StudentRecords& R )
{
  for(unsigned i = 0; i < SomeNumber; i++)
  {
      os << R.GetResults()[i] << '\n'; //this won't work of course see error
  }
  return os;
}
```

There will be an error stating:

```
error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Result' and 'unsigned int')|
```

I already overloaded the << operator in my Result class in order to print out the values in that class. The problem is that I don't know how to iterate through the results array. From what I've googled I understand that you can use some kind of pointer function for example here: [C++: Setters and Getters for Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55192622/c-setters-and-getters-for-arrays)

When I try to write the function like this:

```
Result* GetResults() const;
```

I will get an error stating:

```
error: cannot convert 'const Result' to 'Result*' in return|
```

Leaving out the * allows the code to compile, but predictably I get a bunch of garbage values from my array. So assuming that my class has an array of objects, and those objects have their own variables, how do I print out the values from my array of objects? I appreciate the help.

Comment: The line `return results[MAX_RESULTS];` attempts to return the single `Result` contained a t the `MAX_RESULTS` index of your `results` array. Since no such `Result` exists, this function would be undefined behavior even if it had an appropriate return type. If you want to return a pointer to the beginning of the array, perhaps `const Result* GetResults() const { return results; }`?

Comment: Your attempt to use the function looks like `R.GetResults()[i]` -- why not something simpler like `R.GetResult(i)`? Three fewer characters to type.

Comment: **Do** familiarize yourself with `<vector>` at the first opportunity. `Result results[ MAX_RESULTS ]` is an unholy mix of C++ and C that makes things more complicated than they need be further down the road.

Comment: Use `std::array<>` instead of plain array.

Comment: @Aamir: The use of `MAX_RESULTS` indicates a count of **up to** that number, making `<array>` the wrong choice. `<vector>` *is* the go-to container. Several of the problems inherent to C arrays carry over to `<array>`, making it not an ideal choice to *generally* recommend.

Comment: @JaMiT Yeah, this works! In order to do this I rewrote my GetResults() function into "Result StudentRecords::GetResults(int i) const { return results[i]; }" It just didn't occur to me that a getter can take in an argument.

Comment: @EmilLang Since you got that to work for you, why don't you post it as an answer to help the next person? *(From my perspective, there should be at least five answers posted to this question, each proposing a different approach. The more answers posted by others, the less work for me. :) )*

Answer (score 4):

```
Result StudentRecords::GetResults() const
{
    return results[MAX_RESULTS];
}
```

This is a common newbie misunderstanding. Because you *declared* the array as `results[MAX_RESULTS]` you think that `results[MAX_RESULTS]` somehow means the whole array. But it doesn't, when you are *using* an array `[]` is used to access individual elements of the array. And of course there is no element at index `MAX_RESULTS`, that's past the end of the array.

Bottom line is that the syntax for declarations and the syntax for expressions is not the same.

You could do something like this

```
const Result* StudentRecords::GetResults() const
{
    return results;
}
```

This returns a pointer to the array, not the array itself (which is actually impossible to do in C++). But that should be close enough for now.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to make the output function part of the class so that it can access the `results` array directly. While `operator<<` cannot be literally part of your class, you can make it logically part of the class by declaring it a friend.

```cpp
class StudentRecords {
    friend ostream& operator <<( ost& os, const StudentRecords& R);
    // Rest of the class definition
};

ostream & operator <<(ostream & os, const StudentRecords& R)
{
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < MAX_RESULTS; i++) {
        os << R.results[i] << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}
```

Alternatively, you could avoid friendship by defining a member function that prints the array and having `operator<<` call that member.

```cpp
class StudentRecords {
  public:
    void print_to(std::ostream& os) const
    {
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < MAX_RESULTS; i++) {
            os << results[i] << '\n';
        }
    }
    // Rest of the class definition
};

ostream & operator <<(ostream & os, const StudentRecords& R)
{
    R.print_to(os);
    return os;
}
```

Note that this approach is geared toward the case where nothing else outside the class will need to access the `results` array. If you need external access to the array, you might as well fix your getter (as in other answers) and use that public access for printing.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by various people, there are various things to consider when tackling this issue.

1. The getter for the object array can take an index number (good old int i) to target the element inside the array. e.g. R.GetResult(i)
2. A declaration is not an expression! In my getter I used the expression "return results[MAX_RESULTS];" where MAX_RESULTS is a constant number... but this ends up meaning to return the array at the MAX_RESULTS-th element, clearly not intended.
3. One thing for the future that I am going to try is to create a pointer function to the array member variable.
4. It was suggested to quickly learn about vectors, since the declaration of "Result results[MAX_RESULTS];" is, to put it in the colorful words of a commentator, "an unholy mix of C++ and C that makes things more complicated than they need be further down the road."

Comment: Keep in mind that you are posting an answer to help other people with the same question. Your answer should not be merely a shallow "book report" of what you have read. I would advise adding a code sample to demonstrate your solution. Once you do that, you may find that your answer is easier to read if it focuses on one approach, rather than trying to summarize everything. (Dropping #2 in particular is easy since another answer covers that.) I suggest focusing on #1, explaining why it is a good approach (does not have to be long) and show the new implementation of `GetResult`.

Comment: I'll bear that in mind! Since you already went ahead and typed out a great answer, I'll just tick it if you don't mind?

Comment: I still think you should add your code for `GetResult(i)` to your answer. There are several potential approaches, and it would be good to have examples for each.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach (not always a good approach, but something to keep in mind) is to keep the idea of returning the array, but upgrade from C-style arrays to `std::array`. A `std::array` behaves a lot like a C-style array, but it does not decay to a pointer. This makes it easier to pass the array to and from functions.

```cpp
    // In the class definition

    const std::array<Result, MAX_RESULTS> & GetResults() const {
        return results;
    }

  private:
    std::array<Result, MAX_RESULTS> results;
```

Returning a reference prevents unnecessary copies, and making the reference `const` prevents outside code from changing your data.

With this type of returned value, the expression `R.GetResults()[i]` becomes valid in your streaming operator. In fact, there might be only three changes required in your code to use a `std::array`, and those changes are all demonstrated in the above code block.

- Change the type of `results`.
- Change the return type of `GetResults()`.
- Have `GetResults()` return simply `results`.

(While I also inlined the definition of `GetResults()`, that was just for my convenience, not part of the fix.)

---

However, we can still do better. The name `MAX_RESULTS` suggests that there could be fewer usable results in the array than the maximum. This inference is supported by the use of `SomeNumber` instead of `MAX_RESULTS` in `operator<<`. For an array whose useful size is not known at compile time, a `std::vector` is a more suitable solution.

Unlike switching to `std::array`, a switch to `std::vector` will require changes to some of the code that was not included as part of the question. For example, there is probably a method for adding a result. Instead of tracking how many results have been stored, assigning the new result to the next available spot, and incrementing the count, the new approach would be to `push_back()` the new result. Once everything is converted, the `MAX_RESULTS` constant should be unused hence can be eliminated (this is your first benefit of switching to vectors).

For the code that is in the question, the changes are similar to what was done when switching to `std::array`.

```cpp
  // In the class definition

  const std::vector<Result> & GetResults() const {
    return results;
  }

private:
  std::vector<Result> results;
```

As with the `std::array` approach, your `operator<<` will work as you wrote it, assuming `SomeNumber` is somehow set to `R.GetResults().size()`. You could, though, take the implementation one step further by switching to a range-based loop.

```cpp
ostream & operator <<( ostream & os, const StudentRecords& R )
{
    // Range-based looping removes the need to track indices.
    for (const auto& result : R.GetResults())
    {
        os << result << '\n';
    }
    return os;
}
```

---

The downside of these approaches is that "array" or "vector" becomes part of the interface rather than an implementation detail. It is a judgment call as to which design is preferable.  Personally, if returning a vector is desirable, I would be inclined to put something like

```cpp
    // Container used to store `Result` objects.
    using ResultContainer = std::vector<Result>;
```

in the class definition, then replace all other uses of `std::vector<Result>` with `ResultContainer`. This tells users of your class that they may assume `ResultContainer` is a container and attempt range-based looping over it, but implies that vector-specific functionality should not be assumed. (Implications are weak; better documentation would be better.) This gives you the flexibility to replace `std::vector` with a different container, if there is ever a reason to do so.